# Can function know if it is inside Matlab publish call?

Tags: matlab, publish

Matalb's [`publish` function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/publish.html) is imperfect. For example, when publishing [`table` (build in Matlab object)](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html) it doesn't use HTML's table, but just does monotype plain text printing. On the other hand, if I write my own function, which outputs HTML code, it will be useless in Matlab command line.

Is it possible to write a function, which knows if it is inside publish, and behave differently?